# Video.js: Stretched Videos

Tags: flash, html5-video, mp4, stretch

I have some videos that are getting stretched, which distorts them:

- f4v: FF 19.0.2 OS X and 17.0.1 Windows, when fallback to Flash
- mp4: Safari 5.1.7 Windows

These browsers play them fine with letterboxing: 
 
OS X: Safari 5.1.7, Chrome 25.0.1364.172 
Windows: IE 9.0.8112.16421, Chrome 25.0.1364.172 m 
Adobe Flash player also does letterboxing, so they look alright.

Comment: I've discovered that if you rewind the video to **the start** and play it again, then VideoJS Flash Player does letterboxing. If you go to other menu and come back or reload the page, the same behavior is repeated, no letterboxing unless video is rewinded

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of the problem was in the way the videos were processed, aspect ratio was incorrectly modified

Browsers supporting HTML5/mp4, Safari 5.1.7 Windows is the exception, detect the original aspect ratio and show them correctly doing letterboxing when the container has a different aspect ratio. When VideoJS fallbacks to Flash in FF, its swf player isn't able to do the same the first time plays the video, stretching it to the container size. 3 operations force the player to re-read the metadata:
- Rewinding to the start
- Playing again when the video arrives to the end
- Going fullscreen